# strcmp() string from stdin and string from file

Tags: c, string, list, file, strcmp

I have a problem with comparing string from file.
I want to create a list of words from a file which is a dictionary. I don't know why `strcmp()` return only -1 or 1 even when I use a word from my file. On output I have for example: `1somethingsomething` instead of `0somethingsomething`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


struct words
{
    char *word;
    struct words *next;
};

void pushBack(struct words **headPointer, char string[])
{
    struct words *pointer;
    pointer = *headPointer;
    if (*headPointer == NULL)
    {

        *headPointer = (struct words*)malloc(sizeof(struct words));
        (*headPointer)->next = NULL;
        (*headPointer)->word = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*(strlen(string)+1));
        strcpy((*headPointer)->word, string);

    }
    else
    {
        while (pointer->next != NULL)
        {
            pointer = pointer->next;
        }
        pointer->next = (struct words*)malloc(sizeof(struct words));
        pointer = pointer->next;
        pointer->next = NULL;
        pointer->word = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*(strlen(string)+1));
        strcpy(pointer->word, string);
    }
}

void createList(struct words **headPointer)
{
    FILE *fp;
    char string[80];

    if ((fp = fopen("polski.txt", "rw")) == NULL)
    {
        printf ("Nie mogê otworzyæ pliku test.txt do zapisu!\n");
        exit(-1);
    }
    else
    {
        while(fgets(string, 80, fp) != NULL)
        {
            pushBack(headPointer, string);
        }
    }
}

int seek(struct words *head, struct words **wordBeforePointer, struct words **wordAfterPointer)
{
    char string[80];

    printf("Type a word to seek:\n");
    scanf("%s", string);

    *wordBeforePointer = NULL;
    *wordAfterPointer = NULL;

    if (head != NULL)
    {
        if (strcmp(head->word, string) == 0)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        while(head->next != NULL)
        {
            head = head->next;
            printf("%s", string);
            printf("%s", head->word);
            printf("%d", strcmp(head->word, string));
            if (strcmp(head->word, string) == 0)
            {
                return 1;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    struct words *head, *wordBefore, *wordAfter;
    head = NULL;
    wordBefore = NULL;
    wordAfter = NULL;


    createList(&head);
    printf("%d", seek(head, &wordBefore, &wordAfter));


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: might be the terminating character

Comment: Remember that `strcmp` is case sensitive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `fgets` call does *not* actually remove the trailing newline, so people using this method frequently find that `strcmp` does not work simply because:

```
"thisword\n" != "thisword"
```

If you want to strip it *manually,* you can use something like:

```
while (fgets (inputLine, 80, filePtr) != NULL) {
    // Get size of input line.

    size_t strSize = strlen (inputLine);

    // If there's a newline at the end, remove it.

    if ((strSize > 0) && (inputLine[strSize-1] == '\n'))
        inputLine[strSize-1] = '\0';

    // Do whatever you need to "non-newline" line.

    doSomethingWith (inputLine);
}
```